# DNS redundancy with phantom NS records

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I currently use 2 DNS providers to publish my zone, for the purposes of redundancy. To cut costs/complexity/overhead, I'd like to use a single provider, but I'd still like some redundancy in the event of protracted outages. I also have my own local Bind server on which I publish my zone, but this is not connected to the public internet.

I was thinking I could do the following:

Add an NS records for my zone that points to an ip address that maps to my local Bind server. Under normal circumstances, this IP address would not respond to DNS queries, but in the event there was an outage on my main provider, I could open up this connection and my local Bind server would start responding. When the outage had cleared, I would then roll back the connection.

My understanding of recursive DNS is that local DNS systems will monitor the RTT of authoritative DNS servers and establish affinity with the ones that respond the fastest. If that were true of most local DNS systems, my "phantom" NS server should not receive very many queries while it was offline, which would mitigate any impact on the end user of having such a system.

Is this a reasonable/sensible approach to DNS redundancy?

Comment: Nope, you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: "Add an NS records for my zone that points to an ip address that maps to my local Bind server. Under normal circumstances, this IP address would not respond to DNS queries" This would create bad service and timeouts. The DNS does not work like you think it does. If you have an outage at your main provider you "just" change your NS records and put those of another provider. Or you use two providers in parallel.

Comment: "Phantom DNS servers" as you refer to them are a bad idea.  Why would you not just run a world reachable instance of DNS on your "Phantom server".  If your DNS usage is so low that  you can contemplate this kind of solution, it should not make a noticeable performance on your connection.

Comment: No.1: Changes to NS records at TLD level can take 48 hours to propagate, so that isn't a solution
No.2: Self-maintained DNS services are targets for DDOS, which why people use DNS SAAS, so that isn't a solution either.

Comment: Chose a single DNS provider with multiple servers? That way you still have some redundancy.

Comment: A single provider will still have common dependencies.